# does running a program from a network file run the program locally?

Tags: java, networking, batch-file, exe

It is simple... I have a jar file, and 2 exe files that are shared across the department.  I have them all located on a network drive, and then have each person point their PATH variable to that drive, so when they execute their tasks it can find the jar and exe files.

I have the following setup on each machine

C: (local)
D: (Disk drive)
U: (Network Drive)

and A.exe, B.exe, and C.jar are all on the network drive.

If the people in the department fire off a job that looks like this:

```
U:
cd automation
java -jar C.jar
```

And executables A & B are used by the jar, Which of these events actually happen?

1. Java downloads the jar from the server and executes it, and when the jar wants to use the exe files, it downloads them to the local computer (probably memory) and executes them
2. Java creates a socket connection to the network drive, and then drives the jar over the network, and when the jar wants to use the exe files, the OS creates the socket connection and drives the exe's over the network.
3. something completely different?

Comment: 1) is the answer. Although "download" is not the term I'd choose for this. The local computer simply "loads" the file - the same way it loads an .exe from the local harddisk

Comment: As a complement the way the network are designed on windows, when you map a drive it create a structure on your computer that the SO understand as been local (for use purpose). So when you have a mapped network drive it is like if it was on your local machine, so the execution process occurs as is.

Comment: I think it doesnt mater, if its local drive, pen drive, cd, or network drive. Java virtual machine load byte code from this jar to memory and run it localy

Comment: There needs to be a seperation here between local/networked hard drive and local/networked RAM

Comment: What do the two executables have to do with the JAR file in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java will try to open the file `C.jar` from the `U:\automation\` directory. It does not care whether this is a network share or local file - this distinction is made by the operating system (i.e. Windows) when Java requests it to read that file. The same applies for starting the executables.

This means that your event (1) is the most accurate description, however "download" does not necessarily mean that the whole file is copied to some download directory.

Comment: You're right... copied into local memory is probably a better descripter

Answer (score 1):

The jvm doesn't know it's not stored locally, it tries to run the file just as if it was stored locally.

This causes software(probably samba) on your machine to translate those read calls to network communications, retrieving the executable file according to the jvms wishes, storing it in local memory and then letting the jvm know reading has been finished.

Answer (score 1):

In modern operating systems, filesystem implementations are using abstract structures. Thus, the user space (in general) can't determine if an attached filesystem is "in the box", or lives on some network-accessed resource at the other side of the planet.
So the short answer is, the operating system takes care of starting the java and exe programs "as usual" **(and runs locally).**

Answer (score 0):

The file is loaded over the network share, exactly the same as if they were on a local hard drive (although usually it would perform a little more slowly). They then run on your local computer.